# How can i sum amount group by book_id and order_id

Tags: mysql, sql, sum

I have a table:

```
book_id  order_id  amount
-------- -------   -------
   a      d1         10
   a      d1         10
   a      d1         10
   a      d2         20
   a      d2         20
   a      d3         30
```

i try this

```sql
SELECT book_id,sum(amount) as sum FROM table WHERE book_id= 'a' GROUP BY book_id;
```

Result

```
book_id      sum
--------   -------
   a         100
```

but i want to group them by book_id and sum amount like this

```
book_id      sum
--------   -------
   a         60     ==> d1+d2+d3
```

How would I write a mySQL to SUM row like d1+d2+d3?

Comment: Why do you have duplicate records? What happens if you have an additional record `a/d1/12` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways. The first one is with `Distinct`:

```
Select t.book_id, sum(t.amount)
from
(
   SELECT DISTINCT book_id,  order_id,  amount 
   FROM book
) t
group by t.book_id
```

The second one is with `With`:

```
WITH w AS (
       SELECT DISTINCT book_id,  order_id,  amount FROM book
          )
SELECT book_id, SUM(amount)
  FROM w
 GROUP BY book_id;
```

Answer (score 2):

Given the current data, you would `SUM` based on `DISTINCT` rows:

[Working Test Case - Updated](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=a9a87f428b7b0827cd8be3814a06d508)

The result of all:

```
book_id SUM(amount)
-------------------
a       60
-------------------
```

```
WITH cte AS (
       SELECT DISTINCT book_id,  order_id,  amount FROM tbl
     )
SELECT book_id
     , SUM(amount)
  FROM cte
 GROUP BY book_id
;
```

Add filtering as you wish to either the `cte` term or the final query expression.

```
WITH cte AS (
       SELECT DISTINCT book_id,  order_id,  amount
         FROM tbl
        WHERE book_id = 'a'
     )
SELECT book_id
     , SUM(amount)
  FROM cte
 GROUP BY book_id
;
```

With older versions of MySQL, you can use a `derived table`, instead of a `CTE` term:

```
SELECT book_id
     , SUM(amount)
  FROM (
         SELECT DISTINCT book_id,  order_id,  amount
           FROM tbl
          WHERE book_id = 'a'
       ) AS cte
 GROUP BY book_id
;
```

Trying to `SUM(DISTINCT amount)` is incorrect, since some different orders could have the same `amount` and those would be compressed into one value.

Comment: Only first one works. Others are wrong and don't work.

Comment: They are logically identical, but I added order_id filtering to some as the OP used that logic in the question.

Comment: @Rezu Yes.  Just a typo.

Comment: @Rezu Too tired.  It was book_id, of course, that the OP was filtering.

Answer (score 0):

Try this nested `SELECT`.

```
SELECT book_id, SUM(amount) AS `sum` FROM (SELECT DISTINCT book_id, order_id, amount FROM book GROUP BY book_id, order_id) AS a;
```

Result

```
book_id  sum     
-------  --------
a        60
```

Comment: @basha04 I edited my answer the result is now correct.

Answer (score -1):

```
   SELECT DISTINCT(book_id), SUM(amount) FROM table GROUP BY book_id WHERE book_id ='a';
```